# How to skip null field with lombok @ToString

Tags: lombok

I found with no succes the simple way to use lombok @toString with the skip null field behaviour.

I think create my own toString function for all function using the aspect programmation. Like that i can chek all null field and skip that.

But it is the good practice, or lombok @toString has one option to do that simply?

Best Regards

Answer (score 7):

It's an open issue on Lombok, so it's not part of implementation yet. see [#1297](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1297).

Comment: This is really beyond the scope of the problem. Also, it doesn't look like the Lombok team is really stoked about this feature. 

Really, we just need a way to not have "null" show up for any of the fields. Sounds easy to me.

Answer (score 3):

Not Lombok-y but this helped me, while waiting patiently for Lombok to include this feature in...

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    ReflectionToStringBuilder rtsb = new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this);
    rtsb.setExcludeNullValues(true);
    return rtsb.toString();
  }
```

Comment: This is the best solution without Lombok, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a Lombok way of doing it, so I postprocess the generated String using the following method:

```
/**
 * Removes the null values from String generated through the @ToString annotation.
 * For example:
 * - replaces:  AddressEntity(id=null, adrType=null, adrStreet=null, adrStreetNum=null, adrComplement=null, adrPoBox=null, adrNip=null, adrCity=city, adrCountry=null, adrNameCorresp=nameCorresp, adrSexCorresp=null, adrSource=null, adrSelectionReason=null, validityBegin=null, validityEnd=null, lastModification=null, dataQuality=null)
 * - by:        AddressEntity(adrCity=city, adrNameCorresp=nameCorresp)
 * Note: does not support tricky attribute content such as "when, x=null, it fails".
 * @param lombokToString a String generated by Lombok's @ToString method
 * @return a string without null values
 */
public static String removeToStringNullValues(String lombokToString) {
    //Pattern
    return lombokToString != null ? lombokToString
            .replaceAll("(?<=(, |\\())[^\\s(]+?=null(?:, )?", "")
            .replaceFirst(", \\)$", ")") : null;
}
```

Note that tricky object attributes such as `"when, x=null, it fails"` are not supported (but that's not an issue for my use-case). I could have used https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html to generate the "toString" content, but I wanted to reuse the field exclusion logic behind Lombok `@ToString(excludes="myExcludedField")`.

[edited]

Your class could also implement an interface with a default method:

```
public interface ToStringWithoutNullValuesProvider {
    default String toStringWithoutNullValues() {
        return removeToStringNullValues(toString()); // see method above
    }
}
```

So your class could be something like:

```
@ToString(excludes="city")
public class AddressEntity implements ToStringWithoutNullValuesProvider {
    String city;
    String country;
}
```

then you can call `myAddressEntity.toStringWithoutNullValues()` to get the String representation without null values, but still having the code generated by Lombok (=without using introspection).

Answer (score 2):

You can override toString method like below

```
public class MyClass{

field a;
field b;

@Override
public String toString() {
    Field[] fields = MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
    String res = "";
    for(int x = 0; x < fields.length; x++){
        try {
            res += ( fields[x].get(this)) != null ? fields[x].getName() + "="+ (fields[x].get(this).toString()) + "," : "";
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            
        } 
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Guava:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
            .omitNullValues()
            .add("fieldA", fieldA)
            .add("fieldB", fieldB)
            .toString();
}
```