# Springboot json - ignore missing parameter

Tags: json, serialization

I need to have something like this:

I have an object as @RequestBody:

```
@Data
@ToString
public class TestObj(){
   private String param1;
   private String param2;
}
```

I need to differentiate missing fields vs fields with null values.

ie:

```
{
   "param1":"value",
   "param2":null
}
```

and

```
{
   "param1":"value"
}
```

If I toString the first one, it's fine
{ "param1":"value","param2":null }

but I want the second one to be:
{ "param1":"value" }
(note, it does not have the param2 because it's missing from request)

Currently it's doing like the first one.

In short, I want it to have null if the value is null and I don't want it part of the serialization if it's not there on the request.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe that will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604701/how-to-skip-null-field-with-lombok-tostring

Comment: Thank you, but I need to determine it via key, not the value. If a key is missing (see second json) - I don't want it displayed as key:null. I don't want it displayed at all.