# Ignore null value when using lombok superbuilder

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, lombok

I have a situation using Lombok SuperBuilder to create a constructor for my class
Is there anyway I can create an object using builder without it creating a null value?

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String DOB;
}


StudentReq.builder()
   .name(name)
   .DOB(DOB)
   .build()
```

The result should be StudentReq(name=John, DOB=19051995) but I am getting StudentReq(name=John, email=null, DOB=19051995)

Comment: Java doesn't work that way. If you have declared a field but you haven't assigned any value, then it is `null` by default, provided it is non-primitive.

Comment: What exactly did you think would happen? your jvm would (on runtime) create a new DataType with only the variables you provided?

Answer (score 3):

As others have explained in the comments, you can't omit the field from the object at all. That's just not how Java works.

If you want to omit it from the `toString` only, you can do that by manually writing your own `toString` implementation. It's [not a feature of Lombok's @ToString](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54604701/8681).

Answer (score 1):

No that is not possible.
When an object of data type is created, all the properties in that datatype can either have a value or, it will be null. Property wont disaapear.