# How do I figure out what object my session is trying to serialize?

Tags: spring, serialization, spring-security, spring-4, spymemcached

I recently upgraded to Spring Security 4.2.3.RELEASE.  I'm also using spymemcached v 2.8.4.  I'm running into this situation where for some reason Spring is trying to serialize service implementation classes.  I can't figure out where this is coming from.  The line of my code that the exception refers to is

```
Set<Session> userSessions = (Set<Session>) memcachedClient.get(userId);
...
memcachedClient.set(userId, sessionTimeoutInSeconds.intValue(), userSessions); // dies here
```

with the mysterious error (the "java.io.NotSerializableException: org.mainco.subco.ecom.service.ContractServiceImpl" is buried within) ...

```
09:06:47,771 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-58) UT005023: Exception handling request to /myproject/registration/save: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-serializable object
    at net.spy.memcached.transcoders.BaseSerializingTranscoder.serialize(BaseSerializingTranscoder.java:110)
    at net.spy.memcached.transcoders.SerializingTranscoder.encode(SerializingTranscoder.java:162)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.asyncStore(MemcachedClient.java:282)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.set(MemcachedClient.java:733)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.set(MemcachedClient.java:126)
    at org.mainco.subco.session.service.MemcachedSessionService.associateUser(MemcachedSessionService.java:365)
    at org.mainco.subco.session.service.MemcachedSessionService.setSessionSecurityContext(MemcachedSessionService.java:288)
    at org.mainco.subco.core.security.SubcoSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(subcoSecurityContextRepository.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:198)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:784)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.mainco.subco.ecom.service.ContractServiceImpl
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
```

How do I figure out the object memcache is trying to serialize and thus figure out how it is referencing a service class to serialize?

The point of this question is not how do I make my service class serializable but why is my session trying to serialize it in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm running into this situation where for some reason Spring is trying to serialize service implementation classes.

spring don't try to serialize implementation .

looks lite when you do

```
memcachedClient.set(userId, sessionTimeoutInSeconds.intValue(), userSessions);
```

it's expect for Serializable object ,but userSessions is not.

Set is not serializable , and type that you get

> (Set) memcachedClient.get(userId);

is not serialized to. check if you can cast    memcachedClient.get(userId) to something that is Serializable like HashSets or TreeSet ....

the worst it's you can try BUT you might get CastException

> memcachedClient.set(userId, sessionTimeoutInSeconds.intValue(), (Serializable)userSessions);

---

you can iterate set and do simple check :

```
int count=0;
for(Session session: userSessions ){
    log....
    boolean isSerializable = checkIfSerializable(session);
    count=isSerializable ? count+1 : count;
    log 
}

private static boolean checkIfSerializable(Object value) throws IllegalAccessException {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bf);
        oos.writeObject(value);
        oos.close();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bf.toByteArray()));
        Object o = ois.readObject();
        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("----->>>> Not exactly Serializable : " + value);
    }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: When the Set is created, it is created using "userSessions = new HashSet<Session>();" so I'm already doing what you are suggesting and yet the error remains.

Comment: from your source Set<Session> userSessions = (Set<Session>) memcachedClient.get(userId);    check in debug for userSessions type of Set

Comment: I have verified it is of type java.util.HashSet.

Comment: what about Session ? is it Serializable ?  something in userSessions is not Serializable , if set is , then session is't

Comment: My question is how do I figure that out.  There is probably something in session that's not, but what's the easiest way to know?

Comment: Chech that all in session is serialable. You can check all objects manually  or in debug mode. Also you can get object session and do cast to serializable inteface . Did you try to cast?

Comment: It's hard to say what is exactly wrong without debug or vision about types of object in session

Comment: By checking stuff manually, I assume you mean looking through my code.  I already did taht before posting the question and I'm stuck so hopefully this bounty will bring out some programmatic ways that I ahven't throught of.

Comment: Programatticaly- try wiith reflection

Comment: private static void checkIfSerializable(Object value) throws IllegalAccessException {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bf);
            oos.writeObject(value);
            oos.close();
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bf.toByteArray()));
            Object o = ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not exactly Serializable");
    }
     }

Comment: try this test for userSessions . add method and call before memcachedClient.set
 checkIfSerializable(userSessions);

Comment: and show out put for this :         Class<?>[] inClasses = userSessions .getClass().getInterfaces();
        for(Class c : inClasses){
            System.out.println(c);
        }

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try to enumerate the sessions and the attributes and java-serialize them to a dummy output stream until one fails ? when it fails you print attribute name and value class.

I suppose `session` is `org.apache.catalina.Session`. In your code add:

```
for(Session x : userSessions) checkSerializable(x.getSession());
```

with `checkSerializable`:

```
 private static void checkSerializable(HttpSession s) {
        Enumeration e = s.getAttributeNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = (String) e.nextElement();
            Object value = s.getAttribute(name);
            try
            {
                ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
                out.writeObject(value);
            }
            catch(NotSerializableException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(name + " is not serializable, class is: " + value.getClass().getName());
            }
            catch(IOException e2)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected", e2);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: The Session object I reference isn't actually an HttpSession objecct, but rather one I create .  As such I don't have a "getAttributeNames" method per se.  Is there any way at run-time to print out the object tree of my session, its fields, and then their fields, and so on?

Comment: You could try some dump utility https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301536/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-php-var-dump if that can enumerate values I would also try to serialize them

Answer (score 3):

So what about `org.mainco.subco.ecom.service.ContractServiceImpl`? Is this a spring bean?

I guess it has `scope="session"` and so it's bound to your session as one of it's attributes. And if you want to serialize your session - all of it's attributes has to be serializable.

Comment: I'm not understanding how this answer helps me figure out why is my session trying to serialize it in the first place.

Comment: When your session is being serialized, obviously all of it's attributes has to be serialized too. Apparently your service is one of the session attributes

Comment: I don't wnat it to be.  How do I programmatically view the contents of hte session?